# Split a string to different linked lists in C?

Tags: c

I have a file.txt with a list of strings like this:

```
name;amount 
name2;amount2
```

I have created 3 linked list for each token, but when I come to split each string then store each token in its own linked list, I couldn't do that.

Here's what I did:

```
while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)){
    LIST *node = malloc(sizeof(LIST));
    NAME *node2 = malloc(sizeof(NAME)); //node for the first token
    NBR *node3 = malloc(sizeof(NBR)); ////node for the second token
    node->string = strdup(line);
    node->next =NULL;
    node2->next2 =NULL;
    node3->next3 =NULL;
    printf("%s\n", node->string);
    ptr = strtok(node->string, ";");
    while (ptr != NULL) {
        node2->name=node->string;
        ptr = strtok(NULL, ";");
        node3->nbr=node->string; // node 3 doesn't get the second token, only the first one
        ptr = strtok(NULL, ";");
    }
```

and the output is this:

```
name name2
name name2
```

Comment: well, as per your code, you're using `;` as a delimiter, when you file is having `,`

Comment: use `ptr`.  E.g. `node3->nbr=ptr;`

Answer (score 1):

Keeping aside the logical aspect, You should be using the return value of `strtok()` to access the token.

You need to do something like

```
node2->name= malloc(<some size>);
strcpy(node2->name, ptr);
ptr = strtok(NULL, ";");
if (ptr) 
{
    node3->nbr= malloc(<some size>);
    strcpy(node3->nbr, ptr);        
}
```

Also, don't forget to `free()` the memory allocated by `malloc()` at the end.